# Windows 10 and Boot Camp drivers

Tags: drivers, virtual-machine, boot-camp, windows-10

6th August 2015, Windows 10 has launched quite well. However, there are some people eying the new OS wit little concerns. Mine is: Will Windows 10 work on a Mac - and, that means with a few "accessoirs"?

The responses to the Boot Camp drivers seen confused forth and back on the internet, this is why I ask here for an answer.

Further, with accessoirs I meant virtualization software capable of booting the Boot Camp partition. I would like to know which ones are confirmed to work with this method? I am testing VMWare Fusion and I am still on my trial period. I'd like to buy the right software that is compatible with what I want to run and do.

Comment: ask Apple support if and which Bootcamp version supports Windows 10.

Comment: If you want to know if Windows 10 is support on current version of VMWare Fusion, contact VMWare, or check the VMWare Fusion product information.  A simple answer to that question is **Yes**.  As to when Windows 10 compatible Boot Camp drivers will be released, ask Apple, that honestly likely won't happen till the next update of 10.10 or 10.11.  I don't see a question that really is on topic here at Superuser sadly.  VMware Fusion 8 will provide even better support for Windows 10.